# Stop application/pulse audio changing Bluetooth Profile when joining a call

Tags: 20.04, sound, kubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a pair of bluetooth headphones, and a separate microphone, so I have the headphones set to use the "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" Profile, so the audio quality isn't trash. When, however, I join calls on some conference software, such as Microsoft Teams, the profile is automatically changed from A2DP Sink to HSP/HFP, causing the quality to turn into as if I'm using a mobile phone from the 1980's.

I also, at the same time, wanted to stop application's audio being muted when I join a call, and I discovered a solution to that in the question [How to stop gnome from muting my music?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159104/354505) I assume, therefore, there is likely a similar setting in Pulse Audio to stop it changing the profile when I join a call, but of searchfu hasn't yielded any results and the linked blog in the above answer is a dead link. Does anyone know which I need to (un)comment or amend to stop it changing the profile? As I am using a separate microphone, then changing the profile makes no sense, as the headphone's inbuilt mic shouldn't be being used.

More odd is that if I join to call, change all the settings back (including the input volume as for some reason it resets that too) and then rejoin the call it doesn't change the settings again; it is only the first time I join a call that boot cycle. Also, odd again, when I turn the headphones on for the first time in a boot cycle, they will connect using A2DP sink, and will continue to do so if I power them off and on. If, however, I join a call (which results in the profile change), and then later, after fixing the settings, power the headphones off, and then on again later they will connect using HSP/HFP even though they were using A2DP Sink when powered off here. This suggests it's not Teams that's changing the profile but likely PulseAudio.

Does anyone know how I can stop PulseAudio making automatic choices on what profile to use when I join a call for a Bluetooth device?

Comment: Try to use `blueman`.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, elaborate on that please, @ExploitFate ; the comment on it's own doesn't really help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Easy way**

Install `blueman` and control bluetooth by own.

**Disable autoswith via config**

PulseAudio has [bluetooth module policy](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-bluetooth-policy) that control audio profile:

> Switch the card automatically between HSP/HFP and A2DP for headsets based on heuristics

You can disable this behaviour. Find out `load-module module-bluetooth-policy` line in file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and replace by `load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=0`.

Comment: Adding `auto_switch=0` worked like a charm; I wanted to avoid using Blueman, I remember using it ages ago and not getting along with it (though it's probably progressed a lot in 7 or so years).