# How prohibit applications to change audio settings

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

After last updates of `Skype` and `Microsoft Teams` this two programs messing up audio settings while incoming/outgoing call.
I'm using `Bluetooth` headset as Headphones(`A2DP Bluetooth` profile and not `HFP/HSP`) and internal mic from laptop as source of my voice.
By incoming/outgoing call `Skype` and `Teams` forcing my headset in `HFP/HSP` mode.
In settings of this programs i cannot use system default.
Only Headset or built-in audio.

In [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310841/stop-application-pulse-audio-changing-bluetooth-profile-when-joining-a-call) i found that i need to edit `pulseaudio` config `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

```
Change
load-module module-bluetooth-policy

To
load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=0
```

But it still switches mode.

How can i prohibit this behavior?

Comment: Can you detail the steps you take to fix it after those programs mess it up?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I open Sound settings and in Tab Hardware I switch in my headset from `HFP/HSP` to `A2DP` mode. But after second call this workaround is stopping to work. So i need to restart `Skype` and `Teams`. Other ways i have no `A2DP` option in Hardware tab.